# How do I duplicate a sheet and the scripts without effecting the original sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So we tried duplicating a google sheets, thinking that the bound script would also copy and it didn't, meaning that the new script we created was effecting the original sheet!

After restoring the sheet, we now get a 404 error in the console and a button doesn't work when clicked to load a HTML service. If I load the script from the script editor/onOpen, the page loads fine.

My main question is, how do I duplicate a sheet and the scripts without effecting the original sheet? If anyone knows how to fix the 404 error that would also be ideal!

Answer (score 1):

Usually it shouldn't do that, that happened to me ONE time - it was totally random and I think it's a glitch on google , I copy sheets ALL the time that have scripts bound, and they all only work on the sheet they are attached to.